# How to remove leading and trailing whitespaces for a specific field from the record using awk command?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to remove leading and trailing space in 3rd column of the below text.txt, and append it at the end.:

text.txt ==> Field1 ~ Field2 ~ Field3 ~ Field4 ~ Field5

```
1 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA        
2 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA        
3 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA        
4 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1  B333       ~ TN     ~ USA
```

Expected output:

```
1 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1        
2 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1        
3 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1        
4 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1  B333       ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1 B333
```

However I am getting result as, where the last field all white space got removed including the space which is a word separator.

```
1 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12A1        
2 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12A1        
3 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12A1        
4 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1  B333       ~ TN     ~ USA~12A1B333
```

I have used the below awk to remove leading and trailing space in 3rd column but it is not working. What am I missing?
Code i am using, and all these are removing the white space which are in-between the string. Here I just need to remove the leading and training space, and not white space between the value.

Code 1:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "~" }; {fullrow=$0}; {gsub(/ /, "", $3) } ; { print fullrow"~"$3 }' text.txt
```

Code 2:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "~" }; {fullrow=$0}; {gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+/,"",$3) }; { print fullrow"~"$3 } ' text.txt
```

Code 3:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "~" }; {fullrow=$0}; {gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+/,"",$3) }; { print fullrow"~"$3 } ' text.txt
```

Please help.

Comment: All the statements should be in a single block, not separate blocks.

Comment: You don't put `;` outside code blocks in `awk`.

Comment: To match trailing space you need to use `$` anchor after it.

Comment: `/^ +| +$/` matches leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, this worked. Used the code ```awk 'BEGIN { FS = "~" }; {fullrow=$0}; {gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+/,"",$3) }; { print fullrow"~"$3 }; ' text.txt``` as you suggested. Also as you mentioned that all the statements should be in a single block, please provide some sample code, I am new to the awk, and googling to get the solution. and in one blog i found having multiple blocks {} to write the code, so was following. and till date luckily it worked.  However would like to learn the right way.

Comment: @MayankTripathi: You don't need `{fullrow=$0}` and also note that you have multiple spaces between `12` and `A1` but actually want a single space in output. [See here on how to make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66033273/548225)

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```sh
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*~[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS='~' '{s=$3; gsub(/[[:blank:]]{2,}/, " ", s); sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/, ""); print $0, s}' file

1 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1
2 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1
3 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1
4 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1  B333       ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1 B333
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*~[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS='~' '{
   s=$3
   gsub(/[[:blank:]]{2,}/, " ", s)
   sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/, "");
   print $0, s
}' file
```

Comment: `gsub(/[[:blank:]]{2,}/, " ", s)` only removes 2 or more spaces in a row, it will leave single spaces. And it's not just leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @Barmar the FS setting is already handling leading/trailing blanks in the field and the OP wants to leave single spaces mid-field. The only thing I see wrong with the code is it's not stripping trailing blanks from the lines as in the OPs input.

Comment: @Barmar: Probably you missed `-F '[[:blank:]]*~[[:blank:]]*'` part that takes care of leading+training space. Then we only need to convert 2+ spaces into a single space as per OP's expected output.

Comment: Yes, missed that. I didn't see anything in the question about converting 2+ spaces into a single space. It's not clear to me that this was intentional in the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="~"
}
{
  val=$3
  gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",val)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",val)
  sub(/ +$/,"")
  print $0,val
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                           ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                          ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS="~"                    ##Setting fs and ofs as ~ from here.
}
{
  val=$3                        ##Setting 3rd field value to val here.
  gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",val)        ##Globally substituting starting and ending spaces in val with NULL.
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",val)
  sub(/ +$/,"")                 ##Substituting trailing spaces with null in current line.
  print $0,val                  ##Printing current line and val here.
}
' Input_file                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1
2 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1
3 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1            ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1
4 ABC XYZ     ~400 1      ~ 12    A1  B333       ~ TN     ~ USA~12 A1 B333
```

Comment: `gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",val)` will remove spaces in the middle, not just the ends.

Comment: @Barmar, Hello sir, I think as per OP's shown samples it looks correct to me, I have double checked it now and posted sample output what I am getting too in my answer, kindly do let me know if I missed anything here, thank you.

Comment: Do the `gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",val)` first THEN `gsub(/^ | $/,"",val)` to handle all white space at the start/end of val (as you have it written if `val` started or ended with a tab it wouldn't be removed) and coincidentally slightly improved brevity.